# How to create a linked server to connect azure sql DW and MongoDB?

Tags: sql-server, azure, linked-server

I tried it via SSMS, but i don't see the linked server folder in object explorer.

Tried creating via T-sql stored procedure, but the sp_addlinkedserver (and also other linked server related) does not exist.

I cannot see it in the SP section at all, cannot see it in master DB too. I am using, Azure sql server ADW on cloud, do not see many of the SPs that are other wise available as part of SQL server.

softwares and their versions------->>

1. SQL server version 2019 microsoft sql server 2012 native client
2. installed microsoft odbc driver 17 for sql server installed  SQL
3. Server Management Studio    (SSMS)                  15.0.18206.0 Microsoft Analysis
4. Services Client Tools                       15.0.1567.0 Microsoft Data Access
5. Components (MDAC)                       10.0.18362.1 Microsoft MSXML                        3.0 6.0

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here??

I have been trying to find the definition of the SP sp_addlinkedserver but unable to find it. IF i find this, i will myself add it in the DW. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You can't.. and you shouldn't. I suggest you use a more enterprise grade integration method such as ADF

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what SQL Server you are using? SQL Server in an Azure VM? SQL PaaS? SQL data warehouse? (Synapse).

Comment: azure sql server ( cloud)

Comment: using ADF by creating a linked service is another alternative. But i want to query directly.

Comment: Azure SQL Server doesn't support linked servers. I think there are workarounds with `OPENQUERY` but it's a _bad_ idea.

Comment: I see in many places, they connect with SSMS with the Linked folders option, but i am not able to see that icon itself nor the stored procedure is available. But can you state the stored packages that are available in sql server and azure sql server are varying? there are so many missing in azure

Comment: It's documented somewhere. I suggest you google it. It's a big list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL DW doesn't support [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15):

[image]

If you want copy data between Azure DW and MongoDB, Maybe you can try [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). Reference:

1. [Copy data from MongoDB using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb).
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly Azure
   SQL Data Warehouse) by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse)

Hope this helps.